# Automatically fetching latest version of a file on import

Tags: python, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I have a module that I want to keep up to date, and I'm wondering if this is a bad idea:

> Have a module (mod1.py) in the
>   site-packages directory that copies a
>   different module from some other
>   location into the site-packages
>   directory, and then imports * from
>   that module.

```
import shutil
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
p_source = r'\\SourceSafeServer\mod1_current.py'
p_local = get_python_lib() + r'\mod1_current.py'
shutil.copyfile(p_source, p_local)
from mod1_current import *
```

Now I can do this in any module, and it will always be the latest version:

```
from mod1 import function1
```

This works.... but is there a better way of doing this?

**Update**

Here is the current process... there is a project under source-control that has a single module: `mod1.py`  There is also a `setup.py`  Running `setup.py` copies `mod1.py` to the site-packages directory.

Developers that use the module must run `setup.py` to update the module. Sometimes, they don't and not having the latest version causes problems.

I want to be able to just check-in the a new version, and any code that imports that module will automatically grab the latest version every time, without anyone having to run `setup.py`

Comment: What's wrong with an ordinary "setup.py install"?  Why won't that work?  What is your use case for this?

Comment: Currently we are doing this to make sure we have the latest version.  I want to take that step out because having an old version may cause problems, and sometimes reinstalling is overlooked.  Are you suggesting auto-run setup.py? It would just copy the one file to site-packages

Comment: @coonj: Please update your question with additional facts.   If setup.py install isn't broken, why are you fixing it?  What problems are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases, we put `.pth` files in the Python site-packages directory.  The `.pth` files name our various SVN checkout directories.

No install.  No copy.

`.pth` files are described [here](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html#module-site).

Answer (score 2):

Do you *really* want to do this?  This means you could very easily roll code to a production app simply by committing to source control.  I would consider this a nasty side-effect for someone who isn't aware of your setup.

That being said this seems like a pretty good solution - you may want to add some exception-handling around the network file calls as those are prone to failure.

Comment: Good points, thanks.  Anyone that uses this particular module currently grabs the latest version, so this would be taking that step out of the process.  I guess it is more likely that problems will occur by having using old version rather then automatically using the newest.

Comment: And I'll definitely add exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

The original strategy of having other developers copy mod1.py into their site-packages in order to use the module sounds like it's the real problem. Why aren't they just using the same source control are you are?

This auto-copying will make it hard to do rollbacks, especially if other developers copy your strategy. Imagine this same system used for dozens and dozens of files. And then imagine you actually *do* want to use a version of mod1.py that is not the latest for something.